# Any clear, working example of data fetching across two domains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I want to get some data from a table from another website and post it on a page on a different domain. **I do not have control over the domain from which the data should be taken.** I have tried all the methods I could find on this site and the internet (methods using iframes, CORS, postMessage, etc). None of them worked. It seems a lot of these answers on the cross-origin question assume you have access to the target domain and can use a specific (receiver) file on that domain.

That is just not the case here. I just want to copy some table rows and control that data maybe with jQuery.

Do you know any complete example of a working script I can learn from? I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, but all the sources I've tried until now seem to assume you have to control both domains.

The data I'm trying to fetch has no legal/copyright implications, it's just a top 10 rating list of RTS players from another site. Thanks.

Comment: You can't! Unless you can enable CORS on the server that has the table, there's no way to get it with clientside code. You have to use serverside code to get the HTML and then use jQuery to contact your own server

Comment: If you don't have control over the source domain, then unless they enable CORS to `*`, you won't be able to access it through your own domain. You likely need a server-side proxy.

Comment: Yep no other choice than going server-side for this.

Comment: can also use third party proxy service like Yahoo YQL

Comment: @charlietfl  Can this be done automatically from a script? I see that they can extract JSON data and HTML from a provided link.

Comment: yes, get html returned as json

Comment: Well, I tried using YQL and I get this message: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to fetch some table data from other websites. I used a Google spreadsheet function ([IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)) to get the table in a Google sheet, then I used [TabletopJS](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) to parse the data into Array objects. From there it was very simple, all you had to do is access the arrays and use the data as you wanted to.

Be aware, though, that for large spreadsheets, this method may not be so fast, so when you load the data to another website, by parsing it with Tabletop, it may take a few seconds for it to get loaded.

So, it is a solution which manages to overcome the cross-domain issue in Javascript, but it's not a particularly fast one.

(I will actually accept my own answer even though I don't usually do that, because I think it's a method which can get the job done, when speed is not an issue.)